# "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound" error

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql

I've looked at other questions similar to this but just don't see where the error is.  It could be because i've been up all night trying to get this project done and i was getting a bunch of

ORA-02391 exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit Errors in JIRA

errors but as of right now.  I'm just getting:

QLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

I'm pretty error is occuring right after the user is prompted to input the customer number:

```
private  void delCustomer() {
        try {
              Scanner dinput= new Scanner(System.in);

            //Get a connection to database

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@acadoradbprd01.dpu.depaul.edu:1521:ACADPRD0";
            Connection conn3=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "mlonerga", "cdm0204820" );

            System.out.println("Please enter one of the following account number to delete: ");

            Statement stmt = conn3.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rset.next()) {System.out.println(rset.getString("name") + ", " + rset.getString("customer_num"));
            }

            rset.close();

            // 0. read user input


            System.out.println("Enter enter the customer number Ex...A123x: ");
            String custnum = dinput.nextLine();


            // 2. Create a statement
            String delete = "delete from customers where customer_num = (?)";

            PreparedStatement delmyStmt = conn3.prepareStatement(delete);


            // set values
            delmyStmt.setString(1,custnum);


            // 3. Execute SQL query
            delmyStmt.executeUpdate();


             int rowsAffected = delmyStmt.executeUpdate(delete);

             System.out.println("Rows affected: " + rowsAffected);
             System.out.println("Delete complete.");
             delmyStmt.close();

        }catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the delete statement as below and try executing it.

```
String delete = "delete from customers where customer_num = ?";
```

Let me know if this works.